# Navigation Bar background is hiding right button and cannot remove it on next views

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm using the category below to programmatically change the navigation bar background into my app. It works fine but I cannot see the right button I added in the nav bar. The button seems hidden as tapping on right side nav bar still trigger the action connected to the nav bar right button. Also, how do I remove the navigation background that was added with the given category method ?

**UINavigationBar+CustomImage.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UINavigationBar (CustomImage)
  - (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)image;
  - (void)clearBackgroundImage;
```

**UINavigationBar+CustomImage.m**

```
#import "UINavigationBar+CustomImage.h"

@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)
{
  if(image==nil) return;

  UIImageView *image_view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
  image_view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,44);
  [self addSubview:image_view];
}

- (void)clearBackgroundImage
{
  NSSArray *subviews = [self subviews];
  for(int i=0;i<[subviews count];i++)
  {
     if([[subviews objectAtIndex:i] isMemberOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
     {
         [[subviews objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];
     }
  }

}
```

And in my view controller it's called like this:

```
[[self.navigationController navigationBar] performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setBackgroundImage:) withObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header-background.png"]];
```

Thanks for helping,

Stephane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try sending your view to the back:

```
[self sendSubviewToBack:image_view];
```

placing it at a specific z-index:

```
[self insertSubview:image_view atIndex:0];
```

or below another view:

```
[self insertSubview:image_view belowSubview:anotherSubview];
```

or above another view:

```
[self insertSubview:image_view aboveSubview:anotherSubview];
```